# How is everything happened when a class's metaclass is a subclass of its subclass's metaclass?

Tags: python, inheritance, metaclass, cpython

It is about metaclasses in Python2.7.

To be clear, the code is like:

```
class MetaC(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print "MetaC"
        return super(MetaC, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class MetaB(MetaC):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print "MetaB"
        return super(MetaB, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class MetaA(MetaB):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print "MetaA"
        return super(MetaA, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaA

print type(A)

class B(A):
    __metaclass__ = MetaB

print type(B)

class C(B):
    __metaclass__ = MetaC

print type(C)
```

The results are like:

```
MetaA
MetaB
MetaC
<class '__main__.MetaA'>
MetaB
MetaC
MetaA
MetaB
MetaC
<class '__main__.MetaA'>
MetaC
MetaA
MetaB
MetaC
<class '__main__.MetaA'>
```

It seems that when creating the class `C`, `MetaA.__new__` is called after `MetaC.__new__`.

To figure it out, I looked into the source code and find in `typeobject.c`:

```
static PyObject *
type_new(PyTypeObject *metatype, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    /* some code is omitted here */
    for (i = 0; i < nbases; i++) {
        tmp = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(bases, i);
        tmptype = tmp->ob_type;
        if (tmptype == &PyClass_Type)
            continue; /* Special case classic classes */
        if (PyType_IsSubtype(winner, tmptype))
            continue;
        if (PyType_IsSubtype(tmptype, winner)) {
            winner = tmptype;
            continue;
        }
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,
                        "metaclass conflict: "
                        "the metaclass of a derived class "
                        "must be a (non-strict) subclass "
                        "of the metaclasses of all its bases");
        return NULL;
    }
    if (winner != metatype) {
        if (winner->tp_new != type_new) /* Pass it to the winner */
            return winner->tp_new(winner, args, kwds);
        metatype = winner;
    }
    /* some code is omitted here */
}
```

The `for` loop finds the most deepest subclass `winner`(sorry for my poor english, the code may be much clearer than my words). If it is not `metatype`, `winner->tp_new` will be called. That's why I got the results from my code.

So, what I am wondering is, why is it designed like this?Is there any pragmatic case showing the necessity of doing so?

Plus, I also noticed the error message

> metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

Obviously, in my case, the metaclass of `C`, which is `MetaC`, is not a subclass of any metaclass of its bases. So, is it a NON-STRICT subclass? What does 'non-strict' mean here?

Comment: Why are you studying such advanced aspects of Python still using Python 2? The latest Python 2 is 8 years old now, and It is EOL in 2 years. Whatever you want to active in the "real world" with metaclasses is likely better provided in the latest release (3.6)

Answer (score 0):

Of course the particular cases you bring forth are most fictional.

What happens is that for a given class hierarchy (B that inherits from A), both the features of the metaclasses for A and B must be present to correctly create B. And one way to be reasonably sure the metaclass for B also incorporates whatever the metaclass for A does, is if B's metaclass is a subclass of A's metaclass.

In a more realistic scenario you can have a hierarchy tree that specializes metaclasses, and down on the tree, on a multiple-inheritance scenario, one will want that the metaclass for a class "G" incorporates everything that happens in the various branches from which it inherits.

It is actually the only design that makes sense - even though it is such a corner case it is almost never reached. You rs was a completly artificial example to stress out this corner case, and it just worked out.

**Rephrasing it** for your example, when instantiating your "C" class there, it would mean that although your "C", as a subclass is also a "B" and an "A", the code that needs to be run when initializing "B" and "A" would not have run.

As for the other question "non-strict subclass", it means that derived metaclasses can use multiple-inheritance and be sub-classes of other metaclasses than the metaclasses of its parents, if they inherit from the parent's metaclasses as well.